# How to decode Arabic characters using JavaScript (Only client side solution)

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, decode, encode

I have this text:

```
var txt = 'u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'; // سلام
```

and it means: سلام in Arabic.

I need a JavaScript function that will transform this: u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 to this: سلام for example:

```
function convert(str){
// code here that convert each letter to Arabic for example or another decode solution ...
return  new_str;
}

var txt = 'u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'; // سلام

console.log( convert(txt ) ); // سلام
```

I search for the problem here but all what I get was server side solutions like PHP encoding functions and MySQL connection encode and HTML meta encode (not work also).

Comment: where does the string come from? Is it hardcoded in your program?

Comment: Have you attempted to decode the characters or tried any existing JS libraries? It looks like you just want someone to write the code for you.

Comment: no it's from another website, a dictionary website, I made a crawler to get some text and even in the website itself the characters are is the same form

Comment: @cinnaroll45 nope I search for Arabic decode in JavaScript and all the questions has no answer .. It will be appreciated if you share some of these libraries names with us

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method of doing that:

```js
let txt = '\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'; // سلام
console.log( convert(txt ) );         // سلام

function convert(str) {
return decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"'+str.replace(/\"/g,'\\"')+'"'));
}
```